# Pivoting a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

New to db, I have the below table and  I need to convert the columns values to rows, can somebody please help.

Below is the source data which I already have:

```
id              custom_key  custom_value
648079          WrapUpName  Default Wrap-up Code
648079          agentEmail  abc@gmail.com
648079          Location    Hyderabad
648079          Supervisor  Vinay
648079          Publication xyz
648122          WrapUpName  Default Wrap-up
648122          agentEmail  efg@gmail.com
648122          Location    Mumbai
648122          Supervisor  Pranay
648122          Publication mnp
```

I need to convert the above values to the below format using a PostgreSQL query.

```
id              WrapUpName              agentEmail      Location    Supervisor  Publication
648079          Default Wrap-up Code    abc@gmail.com   Hyderabad   Vinay       xyz
648122          Default Wrap-up Code    efg@gmail.com   Mumbai      Pranay      mnp
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+and+([pivot]+or+[crosstab])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
    max(custom_value) filter(where custom_key = 'WrapUpName') as wrap_up_name,
    max(custom_value) filter(where custom_key = 'agentEmail') as agent_email
    ...
from mytable
group by id
```